# Get multiple value from input field and append them into new row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input which contains multiple value in and separated with comma, and when button clicked i tried to get value of input and replace comma with empty space and append each one of value into new row `<tr>`:

```js
function PostForm() {

  var getVal = $("#Kundenummer").val().replace(/,/g, ''); //11548 10883

  $('#tablebody').append('<tr><td>' + getVal + '</td></tr>')

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Kundenummer" id="Kundenummer" value="11548, 10883,">
<button onclick="PostForm();" type="button">Save</button>
<table id="tablebody"></table>
```

But after getting value of input and append them into table , it will put both value together in one row

```html
<table id="tablebody">
  <tbody id="output">
    <tr>
      <td>11548 10883</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the Output i looking for:

```html
<table id="tablebody">
  <tbody id="output">
    <tr>
      <td>11548</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10883</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are replacing comma with space which will return you the string only, instead you can split string with comma which will return you the array of string and iterate the result to create table

```js
    function PostForm() {
    
    var getVal = $("#Kundenummer").val().split(',');
    
    for(var i=0; i<getVal.length; i++) {
        var val = getVal[i];
        val = val.trim();
        if(val!='') {
          $('#tablebody').append('<tr><td>' + getVal[i] + '</td></tr>');
        }
    }  
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Kundenummer" id="Kundenummer" value="11548, 10883,">
<button onclick="PostForm();" type="button">Save</button>
<table border='1'>
 <tbody id="tablebody">
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks its workin fine i just have little question , after split value , value become like this ["10883","10883"," "] and as you see there is one empty , how can i remove the empty one !

Comment: you can trim the value and compare with empty string, if it is not empty then add to row otherwise skip it. I have updated my answer, please check

Comment: yes i just tried but it also includ empty one and when i append to table it will like this <tr><td>10883</td></tr> <tr><td>10886</td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>

Comment: i have updated my answer with working code snippet to check if it is inserting blank value but i could not reproduce it. can you provide me working code snippet which add empty row, so that i can take a look at it

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

First, use `split` to convert your string to an array:

`var getVal = $("#Kundenummer").val().replace(/,/g, '').split(" ");`

Then, loop over the elements in the array and append a row and column:

`getVal.forEach((e) => $("#tablebody").append(`${e}`));`

Full snippet:

```js
function PostForm() {
  var getVal = $("#Kundenummer").val().replace(/,/g, '').split(" "); //11548 10883
  getVal.forEach((e) => $("#tablebody").append(`<tr><td>${e}</tr></td>`));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Kundenummer" id="Kundenummer" value="11548, 10883,">
<button onclick="PostForm();" type="button">Save</button>
<table id="tablebody">
  <tbody id="output">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this more effectively you need to `split()` the value in to an array by the `,` character. Then you can iterate over the array and build a new table row for each value, before appending the content to the `table`.

Also note that `on*` attributes are outdated and should be avoided where possible. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead. As you've already loaded jQuery in the page, you can use `on()`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var values = $("#Kundenummer").val().split(',');
    var html = values.map(function(value) {
      return `<tr><td>${value}</td></tr>`;
    });
    $('#tablebody').append(html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Kundenummer" id="Kundenummer" value="11548, 10883">
<button type="button">Save</button>

<table>
  <tbody id="tablebody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just as a note, be wary of using a solution which calls `append()` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `split` your input value string to form an array and after that iterate over that array you can add a row for your table. Please see below working code-

```js
function PostForm() {

  $('#tablebody').html('');
  
  var getVal = $("#Kundenummer").val().split(','); //11548 10883

  getVal.forEach(function(val){
    $('#tablebody').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Kundenummer" id="Kundenummer" value="11548, 10883,">
<button onclick="PostForm();" type="button">Save</button>
<table id="tablebody"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` and loop to bind data on `tbody` like below.

```js
var getVal = '11548 10883';
var result = getVal.split(' ');
var html = '';
$.each(result, function(index, value) {
  html += '<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>';
});
$('#tablebody').append(html);
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablebody">
  <tbody id="output">

  </tbody>
</table>
```